# 'Hamburger' icon isn't opening or closing the component - React Navigation V6

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

Would anyone be able to give me help regarding **React Navigation** with Expo? The issue is with the drawer component where the 'Hamburger' icon isn't opening or closing the component when a user presses the icon. However, it does open/close on a default swipe gesture from React Navigation. Please see below for my code:

Router:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer, DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { IconButton } from 'react-native-paper'

import i18n from '../i18n/i18n';

//Theme
import Theme from '../theme/theme'

//Components
import Menu from '../components/Menu'

//Import Interfaces
import { RootDrawerParamList } from '../utils/typescript/type.d';
import { IProps } from '../utils/typescript/props.d';

//Import Screens
import Screen1 from '../screens/Screen1';  
import Screen2 from '../screens/Screen2';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/Settings';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator<RootDrawerParamList>();

export default class Router extends React.Component<IProps, any> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
      super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator 
          initialRouteName='Screen1'
          drawerContent={(props: any) => <Menu {...props} />}
          screenOptions={({
            swipeEnabled: true
        })}>
          <Drawer.Screen 
            name="Screen1" 
            component={Screen1} 
            initialParams={{ i18n: i18n, Theme: Theme }}
            options={({route, navigation} : any) => ({
              headerRight: () => (<IconButton icon="cog" size={24} color={Theme.colors.text} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')} />),
              route: {route}, 
              navigation: {navigation}
            })}
          />
          <Drawer.Screen 
            name="Settings" 
            component={SettingsScreen} 
            initialParams={{ i18n: i18n, Theme: Theme }}
            options={({route, navigation} : any) => ({
              headerTitle: i18n.t('settings', 'Settings'),
              headerLeft: () => (<IconButton icon="arrow-left" color={Theme.colors.text} size={24} onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />),
              route: {route}, 
              navigation: {navigation}
            })}
          />
          <Drawer.Screen 
            name="Screen2" 
            component={Screen2} 
            initialParams={{ i18n: i18n, Theme: Theme }}
            options={({route, navigation} : any) => ({
              route: {route}, 
              navigation: {navigation}
            })}
          />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

Menu

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { List, Title } from 'react-native-paper';
import { getDefaultHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/elements';
import { DrawerItem } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { useSafeAreaFrame, useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

//Import Interfaces
import { IListItem } from '../utils/typescript/types.d';
import { IPropsMenu } from '../utils/typescript/props.d';
import { IStateMenu } from '../utils/typescript/state.d';

//A function is used to pass the header height, using hooks. 
function withHeightHook(Component: any){
  return function WrappedComponent(props: IPropsMenu) {
    /*
      Returns the frame of the nearest provider. This can be used as an alternative to the Dimensions module.
    */
    const frame = useSafeAreaFrame();
    /*
      Returns the safe area insets of the nearest provider. This allows manipulating the inset values from JavaScript. Note that insets are not updated synchronously so it might cause a slight delay for example when rotating the screen.
    */
    const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
    
    return <Component {...props} headerHeight={getDefaultHeaderHeight(frame, false, insets.top)} />
  }
}

class Menu extends React.Component<IPropsMenu, IStateMenu> {
  constructor(props: IPropsMenu) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      menu: [
        {
          name: 'screen1.name',
          fallbackName: 'Screen 1',
          icon: 'dice-multiple-outline',
          iconFocused: 'dice-multiple',
          onPress: this.props.navigation.navigate.bind(this, 'screen1')
        },
        { 
        name: 'screen2.name',
        fallbackName: 'Screen 2',
          icon: 'drama-masks',
          iconFocused: 'drama-masks',
          onPress: this.props.navigation.navigate.bind(this, 'screen2')
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  renderItem = (item : IListItem) => {
    const { i18n } = this.props.state.routes[0].params;

    return (
      <DrawerItem
        label={ i18n.t(item.name, item.fallbackName) }
        onPress={ item.onPress ? item.onPress: () => {} }
        icon={ ({ focused, color, size }) => <List.Icon color={color} style={[styles.icon, {width: size, height: size }]} icon={(focused ? item.iconFocused : item.icon) || ''} /> }
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { headerHeight } = this.props;
    const { menu } = this.state;
    const { Theme } = this.props.state.routes[0].params;

    return (
      <View>
        <View style={{
          backgroundColor: Theme.colors.primary,
          height: headerHeight ?? 0,
        }}>
          <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'column',
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
          }}>
            <View style={{ 
              flexDirection: 'row', 
              alignItems: 'center', 
              marginBottom: 5,
              marginLeft: 5
            }}>
              <Title style={{ color: Theme.colors.text, marginLeft: 5 }}>
                Title
              </Title>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        <FlatList 
          data={menu}
          keyExtractor={item => item.name}
          renderItem={({item}) => this.renderItem(item)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };
}

export default withHeightHook(Menu);


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    alignSelf: 'center', 
    margin: 0, 
    padding: 0, 
    height:20
  },
  logo: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
    marginHorizontal: 8,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
});
```

Comment: Excuse the potential dumb question, but where is the hamburger icon rendered in this JSX? I can't seem to see it

Comment: @adsy its the default one that is created by Drawer.Navigator so no custom JSX. Sorry should of been a little more detailed

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my issue was to encapsulate the drawer component in a native stack component. The 'Hamburger' icon works as expected, thanks for all the help and suggestions.

```
// Import Screens
import DrawRouter from './DrawRouter';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

export default (): React.ReactElement => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={DrawRouter} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the toogleDrawer() method to your onPress event on your Drawer.Navigator component:

```
onPress={()=> navigation.toggleDrawer()
```

Comment: I've tried this and non of the methods to open or toggle the drawer. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Have you tried this way? navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())